# Are the contours of the conditional bivariate normal distribution really elliptical?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I understand that the contours of the bivariate normal distribution are elliptical and rotated $45$ or $135$ degrees if there is positive or negative correlation.  However, I was reading the Rice textbook and I think there was an error.  When stating that the bivariate normal has elliptical contours, the author wrote down the expression contained within the exponent in a simplified case with both means $0$ and variance $1$ writing: $(p^2)(x^2)-2pxy+y^2=$constant.  I then saw that this is the expression contained within the exponent of the conditional bivariate normal distribution $y|X=x$ and not the joint distribution.  I then checked this equation by graphing it and found that it was not an elipse.  It almost was though.  If the $p^2$ term is allowed to be even the slightest bit greater than its value, this equation truly is an ellipse.  Can anyone here with more knowledge confirm that the conditional bivariate normal distribution does not have elliptical contours.  By the way, it would seem to make sense to me that it not be elliptical since $x$ must be a constant before the graph takes the shape of a legitimate density function.  But I still am confused by this.

Comment: I have not read the original source, so I do not fully understand the argument here. The conditional distribution you mentioned is a univariate distribution, so it will not have elliptical contours. Maybe the author means you can infer the joint by looking at this and it will be simpler? Anyway, it is easy to check the bivariate pdf have elliptical contours by looking its exponent.

Comment: Thank you for reaffirming that the conditional it is not elliptical, only the joint is.  I just wanted to be sure. I understand the conditional is univariate and is not meant to be looked at with both variables varying but you can graph it anyways like that in 3D and take a look.  What made me think about this is that the expression I wrote above was said by the textbook to be an ellipse but I found out that it wasn't.  That expression above belongs to the conditional and not the joint so I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.  Thank you for reaffirming.